# Using networkx to retrieve all edges in common to certain nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, edges

Using `networkx` I want to generate a bipartite subgraph from a generic graph. Given two lists of nodes `A` and `B`, I first create the subgraph induced by `A + B`, then I want to delete all the edges between the nodes of `A` and then the edges between the nodes of `B`, leaving unaltered the edges from `A` to `B`. I am currently clueless about how to perform the edge deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the task using sets of edges. Given my subgraph `sub_G`

```
sub_G.remove_edges(set(sub_G.edges(A)) ^ set(sub_G.edges(B)))
```

Comment: Had a similar problem. I wanted to delete all directed edges from a node to neighbor. I did using 

```G.remove_edges_from(set(G.in_edges(neighbor,keys=True)) and set(G.out_edges(node,keys=True)))```

Thanks